# Apache PIG: Get the day of the week and split accordingly

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I need to split dates between two and ignore saturday and sunday from it. Built in function on 0.11.1 will help to get day of the week but how to find out whether that is saturday or Sunday? Anyone has any idea of it? My expected output described below.

**Input:**

User Fromdate Todate

Raj  10/3/2013  10/8/2013

James  10/4/2013  10/7/2013

etc..

**Expected Output:**

Raj 10/3/2013

Raj 10/4/2013

Raj 10/7/2013

Raj 10/8/2013

James 10/4/2013

James 10/7/2013

Answer (score 2):

Since the Pig DateTime objects are really Unix epoch time in milliseconds, 
this can be easily done with out-of-the-box Pig operators.

```
(DaysBetween(ToDate('10/3/2013','MM/dd/yyyy'),ToDate(0L)) + 4L) % 7
```

- Yields a long in range 0...6, where 0 = Sun, 1 = Mon, ... etc
- 0L represents 1/1/1970, a Thursday
- Adding 4L days makes 0 = Sunday

Satisfy yourself that this is so from Unix command line:

```
$>  date -d '1/1/1970' +%w-%a   
4-Thu     
$>  date -d '10/3/2013' +%w-%a  
4-Thu
```

Of course, if you are comfortable with UDF, and this is a commonly occurring requirement, that's the best solution.

Carter Shore

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to write a UDF.  You can use Java's [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class to do this.