# How to extract all Sundays of the month in Pig

Tags: apache-pig

Hi!

I have a dataset with id:chararray and date:chararray. Now, I want to filter out the dataset to those rows which start with:

- If the first day of the current month is Sunday, pick all the Sundays of the current month only.
- Otherwise pick the last Sunday of the previous month and all the Sundays of the current month.

So, for given below set

```
12456,  27-04-2014 (last Sunday of the previous month)
33578,  29-04-2014 (not Sunday)
43789,  04-05-2014 (Sunday)
57689,  06-05-2014 (not Sunday)
67890,  11-05-2014 (Sunday)
67845,  13-05-2014 (not Sunday)
57689,  18-05-2014 (Sunday)
33578,  25-05-2014 (Sunday)
```

The output would be

```
12456,  27-04-2014 (last Sunday of the previous month)
43789,  04-05-2014 (Sunday)
67890,  11-05-2014 (Sunday)
57689,  18-05-2014 (Sunday)
33578,  25-05-2014 (Sunday)
```

So, is there a way I can easily get to find the Sundays of the current month and if the first day of the month is not Sunday pick the last Sunday from previous month.

I have all the Date functions available for me like DaysBetween and GetDay in Pig.

Comment: You can execute shell script commands inside your pig code. Shell script command date might help you here.

Comment: Any idea how can I find out in pig what is the last day of the current month. Like any built-inAPI which returns a String whether it is Saturday , Sunday or Monday. .

Comment: Pig does not have rich set of features/libraries that you have in other languages like Java, C++ etc. Pig is for writing MapReduce abstractions and have a great feature of UDF (User Defined Function) which you can use to call Java/Python written functions from pig.

Anyways, to answer your question, execute shell command from inside your pig script:

`date -v31d -v+1m +'%a'`

Answer (score 0):

From [Apache PIG: Get the day of the week and split accordingly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19152907/apache-pig-get-the-day-of-the-week-and-split-accordingly)

```
(DaysBetween(ToDate('03-10-2013','dd-MM-YYY'),ToDate(0L)) + 4L) % 7
```

You can then filter on the returned value